# How to connect Azure federated root database and apply federation in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, azure, azure-sql-database

I tried the following code:

```
CrmEfEntities dc = new CrmEfEntities(federatedRootDBConnectionString);
string federationCmdText = @"USE FEDERATION Customer_Test_Federation (testId=100) WITH FILTERING=ON, RESET";
dc.ExecuteStoreCommand(federationCmdText);  
var count = dc.Projects.Count();
```

I got the exception saying - {"Invalid object name 'dbo.Project'."}
It connected to the Federated root database. Executed the Federation sql command. But I am not getting the entity object. I'm using EntityFramework 4.0 . Anybody knows this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to open the connection before the USE FEDERATION command

```
using (DemoEntities db = new DemoEntities())
{
   db.Connection.Open();
   string federationCmdText = @"USE FEDERATION ProdutosFed(ID = 110) WITH RESET, FILTERING=OFF";
   db.ExecuteStoreCommand(federationCmdText); 
}
```

Comment: and execute any other related actions within that using statement (i.e. db.Projects.Count() or whatsoever). More info can be found here: http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/09/sql-azure-federations-entity-framework-code-first/